The Use and Misuse of the Term Linearity in Physical Sciences
I am searching the definitions of the term "linearity" in leading mathematics dictionaries, and I am trying to understand the reason we call $f(x)=mx+b$ the "linear equation" in physical sciences when it may not meet the definition of linearity. I am not a mathematician but I am under the impression that a function is linear if:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)\\
&\text { and }\\
&f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)
\end{aligned}
$$
If we have a nonzero $b$, I am under the impression that the criterion are not met.
I consulted Lexikon der Mathematik: Band 4 which provides the following text:
Man beachte: Im Sinne der linearen Algebra wird durch $f(x)=a x+b$ im Fall $b \neq 0$ keine lineare, sondern eine affin-lineare Abbildung $f$ definiert.
English Machine Translation: Note: In the context of linear algebra,( $f(x) = a x + b $) does not define a linear mapping when $b$ $\neq$ $0$; rather, it defines an affine-linear mapping $f$.
My question is should $f(x)=mx+b$ be considered a linear equation or an affine equation? Additionally, how does a "linear function" differ from "linear mapping?"
Thank you!

It is called "linear" for historical reasons, the proper name is "affine."

I would say it’s a question of high-school and precalculus terminology versus more advanced mathematical terminology. It is confusing at times.

To your title: physicists know the difference between linear and affine linear very well.

The graph is a line.

These are definitely two distinct, and contradictory, meanings for the single word 'linear '. Sometimes the context will tell you which one is intended - for example, a "linear transformation" never refers to the $mx+b$ version.
But sometimes you just have to ask, and I'd probably say "Do you mean the 'high-school, graph is a line' linear, or the 'linear algebra' linear?". Although since you've included 'in the physical sciences' in your question, I might distinguish the two by asking "Are you assuming that the constant term is zero there?".

The usage of the term "linear" in mathematics dates back to the 17th century as per the unabridged Oxford Dictionary so it is not surprising that it has various shades of meanings in mathematics or physics and chemistry. Like the pigeon-hole principle, there must be multiple usages of the same word, just like the letter $x$ can stand for a lot of things. All usages of the term linear are correct as long as the context is provided by the writers.
The most common usage of linear implies a geometric connotation in physical sciences from school onwards, for example, a linear relation between two variables can be described by a straight line - purely geometric meaning here, whether the intercept is zero or not. Similarly a calibration curve, which plots an instrument's signal against concentration, can be depicted by a straight line (a geometric notion), hence a linear relationship exists between the two variables. Here linear can be interpreted as "having the direction of a line".
Linearity can also indicate direct proportionality, for example volume of a gas $V$ directly proportional to the absolute $T$, $V\propto T$ or $V= cT $, where $c$ is a constant of proportionality. Chemists or physicists will call this a linear relation between the two variables. Geometrically, this will represent a polynomial $p(x)=ax+b$.
In abstract mathematics, the term linearity loses its conventional geometric straight line meaning and then one has to make a distinction between linear and affine, and this is beautifully explained by Lyle Ramshaw on in his essay Blossoms are Polar Forms, https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-8396(89)90032-0

Note on "linear" versus "affine": The word "linear" in mathematics
sometimes implies homogeneity and sometimes doesn't. A polynomial
$F(x)$ is linear if it has the form $F(x)=a x+b$, where $b \neq 0$ is
usually allowed. If we reinterpret $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow
\mathbb{R}$ as a transformation of a 1-dimensional linear space,
however, we must have $b=0$ in order for $F$ to be called linear; that
is, $F$ must also be homogeneous. To avoid confusion, the word
"linear" in this report always implies homogeneity. When homogeneity
is not implied, we use the word "affine." Under this convention, the
polynomial $F(x):=x+1$ is not linear, but it is affine.
More abstractly, an affine combination is a linear combination whose
scalar coefficients sum to 1 . A function is affine if it commutes
with affine combinations, while an affine space (or flat) is a set of
points that is closed under affine combinations.

Thus with this labeling scheme, an affine function of a mathematician, does not satisfy the rigorous conditions of linearity as alluded to in the $Lexicon$ $der$ $Mathematik$. However, for a physical scientist $y=mx+b$ remains to describe the linear relationships between variables and they will continue to loosely call it a linear function because it represents a straight line for them. However, the context is clear.
Another source of confusion arises in optimization theory when we use the terms linear regression, often used to fit $y=mx+b$ type functions. Here the term linear has nothing to do with straight lines or even affine functions but rather the parameters to be optimized have a power of 1. In polynomial regression, the relationship between the independent variable ( x ) and the dependent variable ( y ) is modeled as a polynomial, but the model remains linear in its parameters.
Consider a quadratic (second-degree polynomial) regression:
$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2 + \epsilon$
where:

$y$ is the dependent variable,
$x$ is the independent variable,
$\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, and $\beta_2$ are the parameters (coefficients) to be estimated,
$\epsilon$ represents the error term.

Although the model includes a term $x^2$, making the function non-linear in $x$, it remains linear in parameters, $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, and $\beta_2$. This means that the model can be solved using ordinary least squares techniques typical in linear regression, as the relationship between $y $ and the parameters is linear.
In calculus we encounter linear differential equations.
In short, one can continue to provide examples and counter-examples on the usages of the linear in physical sciences and abstract mathematics. The context matters. As long as no further affine transformations are to be applied on calibration curves or graphs that represent proportional relationships, perhaps it is okay to stick to the language used by the majority and not that of an abstract mathematics.

About the usage of the adjective "affine", see the excellent answers here.

I know what is common, I am wondering the correctness of such use. In a calibration curve we desire a linear or "proportional" response from the instrument where an $x$ of $0$ should give a response of $0$, not a non-zero integer. I am now under the impression that the response is not linear or proportional if a non-zero $b$ is needed, regardless of whether it falls on a line or not.

To add to the confusion, "linear" to an engineer often means that small changes in one variable (the input) result in small changes in another variable (the output).

Perhaps the engineering convention of calling something linear, arises from Taylor series expansion.

@TroyHandlovic - Not everything has a universally agreed-upon meaning, some terms are used for a collection of related meanings - and correctness, in the strict sense, is context-dependent. Different (sub)disciplines may use the same word to denote subtly different things. Yes, this causes some confusion, but is nevertheless true of math, science, engineering, and anything else out there. In any work, the exact meaning or definition of the term in a given context may be (and often is) stated explicitly, and then a usage is correct if it is in accordance with that definition.

We usually teach students to graph "linear" functions --- but as you say, they're not really linear functions --- after we teach them how to solve linear equations like $$ax + b = 0$$ In this equation case, we really do mean "linear" because we're asking for what input $x$ does the linear map $l(x) = ax$ output $-b$.
We probably avoid using the phrase "affine function" so students won't be confused.
To answer your last question, there is no difference between "linear function," "linear mapping," "linear map," or "linear transformation." They're all different words for the same concept.
